# Comparing and matching two sounds in android

Tags: java, android

I need to capture sound from android version 2.3 mic and match it with a wave file stored on card.

If it does match then I need to trigger a specific action.

Comment: Basically you have to implement discreet Fourier Transformation (DCT or DST). http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/

Answer (score 1):

if these are voice samples, and you need a professional solution, you can use the PESQ algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESQ
Or the newest POLQA:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POLQA
These standards are used in telco voice quality solutions.